# Add description to categories menu in admin

Tags: categories, theme-development

I'm trying to create a simple paragraph above the categories menu, on the post editor page. Most of the tutorials I see are adding input meta values, and not in relation to the categories.

What's the best way to add a paragraph of content into the post-editor page (above the categories menu)?

Comment: Are you referring to the Category meta box module on the Edit Post screen?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is for the built-in Category taxonomy for Posts? This would be the way of doing it.

```
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'my_custom_category_paragraph', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_category_paragraph( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ) {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    if ( 'category' !== $taxonomy )
        return;

    // Change the callback that renders the metabox with our own.
    $wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy]->meta_box_cb = 'my_category_metabox_paragraph';
}

function my_category_metabox_paragraph( $post, $box ) {
    // add our paragraph here
    echo '<p>Hi there, sailor!</p>';
    // Call the default meta box function
    post_categories_meta_box( $post, $box );
}
```